# how i could start workflow in feature event receiver FeatureActivated event

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

my business is how i could make some initializations for my sharepoint site, that consist essentially to display custom SPLit view because i have more custom view for each group of users, before any workflow could be triggered, i imagine whether there's any way to that in feature event reciever FeatureActivated event or other way:

please i need your helps:

```
   public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your workflow programmatically as:

```
WorkflowManager = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WorkflowManager;
SPWorkflowAssociationCollection associationColl = ParentList.WorkflowAssociations;
  foreach (SPWorkflowAssociation association in associationCollection) {
    // We can find the association by BaseId or by workflow association name.
    // if (String.Compare(objWorkflowAssociation.BaseId.ToString("B"), {"Workflow_GUID"}, true) == 0)
   // you can identify the workflow association by association name, entered during association creation.
  if (association.Name == wfName)        {
    association.AutoStartChange = true;
    association.AutoStartCreate = false;
    // We can change the
    association.AssociationData = string.Empty;
    // We can use other overload StartWorkflow methods.
   spSite.WorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(listItem, association,  association.AssociationData);
  }
}
```

Also Check:

http://blog.mmasood.com/2012/06/programatically-start-workflow.html

http://jainnitin2411.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/programmaticallystartsharepointworkflow/

Comment: thank so much i'll try that